# How to exclude jackson library without excluding resteasy in JBoss EAP 7.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I want to use my custom Jackson version in JBOSS. For that I want to exclude native jboss jackson library and add my version as gradle dependency.
I also use resteasy in the project and don't wanna exclude jax-rs module.
Is it possible?
Tried configure

> jboss-deployment-structure.xml

but it doesn't help:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />

            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.databind"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

> objectMapper.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()

always terurns

> 2.8.9.redhat-1

Comment: Whats the structure of your deployment?

Comment: I have several ear files and all of them using resteasy and object mapper.I have Polymorphic deserialization fails when use this version of objectMapper, also tried newer version in JBoss EAP 7.2 but have the same issue. So I want to find the way to replace jacson version on custom.

Comment: Do you have CDI enabled in your project (@Inject) ?

Comment: Ariel Carrera, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that jackson library is a dependency of the `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider` module. And that module is an automatic dependency of any WAR subdeployment of your EAR that uses JAX-RS annotations (See Table 3.1. Implicit Module Dependencies of the Redhat 7.2 Development Guide).

You need to exclude the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` module but at the subdeployment level of your WAR using JAX-RS, and redefine it to exclude all the jackson dependencies. You can see this aproach with a similar case (modules included by automatic dependencies) https://developer.jboss.org/thread/175075

I've tested this on JBoss 7.2.6

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">

    <sub-deployment name="myrestmodule.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

    <module name="deployment.org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="com/fasterxml/jackson/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </module>

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The required jackson libs must be included on myrestmodule.war WEB-INF/lib folder.

**UPDATED**

This aproach doesn't work if jackson is used in other libraries of the EAR and not only on the WAR using JAX-RS. For example, if a bean in JAR in the library directory of the EAR is used on the WAR, jackson won't recognize the annotations in it.

For this deployment to work, the exclusion of the "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" module needs to be done at the EAR deployment level, and the jackson libraries need to be included in the library directory of the EAR instead of the WEB-INF/lib of the WAR.

This would be the updated jboss-deployment-structure.xml on the META-INF directory of the EAR:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>

    <sub-deployment name="myrestmodule.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>

    <module name="deployment.org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="com/fasterxml/jackson/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: According to the xsd on $JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema/jboss-deployment-structure-1_2.xsd it's a valid document. Did you place it on the META-INF/ folder of your EAR?

Comment: areus, maybe you now why I have Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.util.HashMap of media type: application/json when I add HashMap  in Response like this: Response.ok(config).build(new HashMap()...);

Comment: Maybe you are missing some of the jackson dependencies that now must be on your WEB-INF/lib. `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` should be one of them. Also include a beans.xml file on your WEB-INF dirctory with `bean-discovery-mode="all"` to make sure annotated beans on the libraries are found.

Comment: I add jackson-core , jackson-annotations and jackson-databind dependency in gradle.xml but all @JsonProperty annotation ignoring for some reasons...

Comment: Maybe on EAP 7.1.0 it is imposible to exlude jacson withou excluding resteasy

Comment: You are missing jackson-jaxrs-json-provider as gradle dependency

Comment: jackson-jaxrs-json-provider also didn't helped and jackson-module-jaxb-annotations also. Object Mapper works good but all  com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation* ignores when respose returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208505/discussion-between---and-areus).